# TkInter Python: Destroyed widget still shows and covers new widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm making a GUI which has radio buttons to select different information to be shown. It can show a treeview or a matplotlib graph. The treeview works well, and I can switch back and forth between different trees. If I start with the graph it shows well too. The challenge is if I go from the tree view to the graph view, the graph is hidden behind the treeview, even though the treeview has been destroyed.

```
elif self.show.get()=="graph":
    f = makeGraph(int(self.gameType.get()))
    for child in self.display_frame.winfo_children(): child.destroy()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master = self.display_frame)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,S,E,W))
```

The makeGraph function simply returns a matplotlib Figure object.

I would expect that the treeview disappears, the graph appears and the frame is resized to accommodate the (larger) graph.

Instead, the frame is resized (and a small portion of the graph is visible at the bottom), but the treeview is resized with it, and somehow remains despite being destroyed.

The treeview is created with the following code elsewhere:

```
for child in self.display_frame.winfo_children(): child.destroy()
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=self.tree_headers, show="headings")
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
#hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W), in_=self.display_frame)
```

Comment: Throwing in a print statement into the self.display_frame.winfo_children() it seems that it's not destroying anything.  So I guess using the .grid(in_=self.display_frame) does not make it a child of self.display_frame?

Comment: So even if I change it to self.tree.destroy(), where it definitely destroys the tree, the tree still shows.

Comment: is `mainloop` running? This sounds a little like tkinter isn't being given the opportunity to redraw the screen.

Comment: Mainloop is still running. All the other buttons etc continue to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some playing around, I realised that

```
for child in self.display_frame.winfo_children(): child.destroy()
```

does not reliably destroy the treeview.  It doesn't even find it.  I think this must be related to the way the tree was created.  The hierarchy was established with the key word "in_" inside a grid call.  So I changed the code to explicitly delete the offending widgets and things improved.

```
f = makeGraph(int(self.gameType.get()))
try:
    self.vsb.destroy()
except:
    pass
try:
    self.tree.destroy()
except:
    pass
try:
    self.toolbar.destroy()
except:
    pass
try:
   self.canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()
except:
   pass

self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f,master = self.display_frame)
self.canvas.show()
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( self.canvas, self.display_frame )
self.toolbar.update()
self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```